# Change css of a global used class in one specific menu?

Tags: joomla-3.x, css, bootstrap, jhtml

So i want to change the css layout on the page but only in one specific menu.

@media screen and (min-width: 768px)
.t3-sl {
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

-div class="wrap **t3-sl** t3-sl-1"-
[look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkBA4.png) and [css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9zv8.png)

If i simply change the css in the custom css all pages with the corp layout are changed. How do i only select the menu kontakt to get the changes?

Comment: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/10195/custom-css-page-class

Answer (score 0):

For now i worked around the problem myself, by giving the module in the screen a margin-bottom of -50px.
Now it all is a bit tighter.

If someone of you out there know the solution of my problem, don't hesitate to post.